# Expected size of a random subset of $\{1,2,3,\dots,N \}$, each element selected with probability $\delta$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

As the title suggests, suppose we form a set $A$ by selecting each element in $\{1,2,3,\dots,N\}$ with probability $\delta$ independently.

What is the expected size of $|A|$? The book I am reading claims it is $\delta N$.

By definition of expectation, this should be equal to $\sum_{n=0}^N n$ $N\choose n$ $\delta^n (1-\delta)^{N-n}$. I'm struggling to show this is equal to $\delta N$.

Comment: Hint: Let $E(n)$ be the expected size when drawing from a set of size $n$.  Can you show that $E(n)=\delta+E(n-1)$?

Comment: You can take a factor $N\delta$ outside the sum (both being constants) and think about what that does to the individual summands.